# Prove that it is a metric

Tags: real-analysis

Hello I have problems with this exercises:

Denote by ${\mathbb{R}}^\infty$ the set of all sequences in $\mathbb{R}$. For $x,y$ define $d$

$d(x,y)= \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty{} \displaystyle\frac{1}{n!} \displaystyle\frac{|x_n-y_n|}{1+|x_n-y_n|}$

Prove that $d$ is a metric

I have to prove the following axioms:

i) $ d(x,x)=0 $

ii) If $ x \neq y $, then $ d(x,y) > 0 $

iii) $ d(x,y)=d(y,x) $

iv) $ d(x,z)\leqslant d(x,y)+d(y,z) $

$d(x,y)= \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty{} \displaystyle\frac{1}{n!} \displaystyle\frac{|x_n-y_n|}{1+|x_n-y_n|} \rightarrow{0}$ as $n\rightarrow{\infty}$

This means that, for $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an integer $ n_0(\epsilon$ such that:

$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty{} \displaystyle\frac{1}{n!} \displaystyle\frac{|x_n-y_n|}{1+|x_n-y_n|} < \epsilon $

and so

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{n!} \displaystyle\frac{|x_n-y_n|}{1+|x_n-y_n|} < \epsilon$

I don't know how to continue

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}?$

Comment: What is meaning of $\sum_{i=1}^n{\infty}$?

Comment: $i$ doesn't appear anywhere.  This must be a mistake.

Comment: The correct is $d(x,y)= \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty{} \displaystyle\frac{1}{n!} \displaystyle\frac{|x_n-y_n|}{1+|x_n-y_n|}$

Comment: Just checking: Can you show that the expression in each summand defines a bounded metric on the reals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proofs of i), ii) and iii) are trivial (very easy), so we are going to prove iv).

Since $\;\left|x_n-z_n\right|\leqslant\left|x_n-y_n\right|+\left|y_n-z_n\right|\;,\;$ it results that

\begin{align}\dfrac{\left|x_n-z_n\right|}{1+\left|x_n-z_n\right|}&=1-\dfrac1{1+\left|x_n-z_n\right|}\leqslant\\&\leqslant1-\dfrac1{1+\left|x_n-y_n\right|+\left|y_n-z_n\right|}=\\&=\dfrac{\left|x_n+y_n\right|+\left|y_n-z_n\right|}{1+\left|x_n+y_n\right|+\left|y_n-z_n\right|}=\\&=\dfrac{\left|x_n+y_n\right|}{1+\left|x_n+y_n\right|+\left|y_n-z_n\right|}+\dfrac{\left|y_n-z_n\right|}{1+\left|x_n+y_n\right|+\left|y_n-z_n\right|}\leqslant\\&\leqslant\dfrac{\left|x_n+y_n\right|}{1+\left|x_n+y_n\right|}+\dfrac{\left|y_n-z_n\right|}{1+\left|y_n-z_n\right|}\;.\end{align}

Consequently,

\begin{align}\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty\dfrac1{n!}\dfrac{|x_n-z_n|}{1+|x_n-z_n|}&\leqslant\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty\dfrac1{n!}\dfrac{|x_n-y_n|}{1+|x_n-y_n|}+\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty\dfrac1{n!}\dfrac{|y_n-z_n|}{1+|y_n-z_n|}\end{align}

that is

$d(x,z)\leqslant d(x,y)+d(y,z)\;.$